# Laravel Nova metric Value range - dates range

Tags: laravel, metrics, laravel-nova

Is there any simple way to create range of 'this week', 'last week' in the ranges function in value metric?
Or maybe can I use starting and ending date in the ranges function? that will also do the job.

For example:

```
public function ranges()
    {
        return [
            'TODAY' => __('Today'),
            $thisWeek => __('Week To Date'),
            $lastWeek => __('Last week'),
            'MTD' => __('Month To Date'),
            'QTD' => __('Quarter To Date'),
            'YTD' => __('Year To Date'),
            1095 => __('Last 3 Years'),
        ];
    }
```

I'm trying to get the SUM off specific column of a Collection. The calculate function looks like that.

```
public function calculate(NovaRequest $request) 
{ 
return $this->sum($request, Subscription::class, 'quantity', 'created_at')->prefix('$'); 
}
```

I don't want to change the calculate function, I'm looking for a solution where I can change only the ranges function.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what type of input and output are you expecting ? unix timestamps / dates / date time? have you tried using carbon?

Comment: Edited the question, I hope it will be more relevent.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask